# Javascript object property 'null' when iterating through an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iteration

I have an array of objects. Somehow, one of the properties goes missing within my each loop. I have tried many different types of loops and nothing resolves this issue.

```
someFunction(someArrayOfObjects) {
    console.log(someArrayOfObjects); // logs objects as I expect them to be

    $.each(someArrayOfObjects, function(index, someObject) {
        console.log(someObject); // one of the properties of someObject is 'null'
    });
}
```

**UPDATE: How the array is constructed:**

```
// constructor
var people = [];
var Person = function (name, age, photo) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.photo = null;
};
```

Then use ajax to get some JSON and create the objects

```
    success: function(data) {
        people.push(new Person(data['name'], data['age'])
}
```

Then I iterate through each of those people and make another AJAX request to get each of their photos. The callback looks like this:

```
function(person, photo) {
    person.photo = photo;
});
```

I am new to javascript and async programming so wrapping my mind around callbacks was tough. I thought I had figured it out when `console.log(someArrayOfObjects)` worked as I expected. I just can't figure out why the photo property reverts when the objects are logged individually. 
I also tried rewriting everything in CoffeeScript because the syntax is a bit easier for me, but unfortunately the issue remains.

Thank you.

Screenshot of console:
[image: screenshot of console]

Comment: Can you provide simple example of your array?

Comment: `var someArrayOfObjects = [
        {name: "joe", age: "32", photo: "joe.jpg"},
        {name: "alice", age: "5", photo: "alice.jpg"},
        {name: "john", age: "22", photo: "john.jpg"}
]`  @user3272018

Comment: The code given appears to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NEW UPDATE and final answer at last**

Below is the sample code, here after all ajax calls are finished then only the **buildQuiz()** function would be called meaning all data is ready for further use.

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) )
  .then( buildQuiz, myFailure );
```

**OLD UPDATE**

As of now(might get three times but) just try below code and let me know the log..

```
function getCastMembers(movieTitle) {
  getNames(movieTitle, function(castMembers) {
    getPhotos(castMembers, function(castMember, photo) {
      castMember.photo = photo;
      buildQuiz(castMembers);
    });
  });
}
```

**OLD UPDATE**

So It appears there has to be something going on between first and sceond log statements.

```
var people = [];
var Person = function (name, age, photo) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.photo = null;
};
var someArrayOfObjects = [ {name: "joe", age: "32", photo: "joe.jpg"},
{name: "alice", age: "5", photo: "alice.jpg"},{name: "john", age:"22", photo:"john.jpg"}]; 
for(i in someArrayOfObjects){
 people.push(new Person(someArrayOfObjects[i]['name'], someArrayOfObjects[i]['age']))
}

people.forEach(function(person,index){
   person.photo = someArrayOfObjects[index].photo;
})
function somefunction(people){
    console.log(people); // logs objects as I expect them to be
       people.forEach(function(person) {
           console.log(person);
       })
}
somefunction(people);

OUTPUT

VM359:17 [Person, Person, Person]
0: Personage: "32"name: "joe"photo: "joe.jpg"
__proto__: Person1: Person2: Personlength: 3__proto__: Array[0]

VM359:19 Person {name: "joe", age: "32", photo: "joe.jpg"}
VM359:19 Person {name: "alice", age: "5", photo: "alice.jpg"}
VM359:19 Person {name: "john", age: "22", photo: "john.jpg"}
```

**OLD UPDATE**

In your success callback of `photo` data call the function to iterate.

```
success: function(data) {
     for(){
         person.photo = data.photo;  // maybe something like this
                                     // you have within for loop
                                     // or something
    }
    // so after all persons filled
    // up with photo now call iterator
    somefunction(someArrayOfObjects);
}
```

**OLD ANSWER**

Below code works fine. Try it out.

```js
var someArrayOfObjects = [ {name: "joe", age: "32", photo: "joe.jpg"}, {name: "alice", age: "5", photo: "alice.jpg"}, {name: "john", age: "22", photo: "john.jpg"} ]; 
      
   function somefunction(someArrayOfObjects){
        console.log(someArrayOfObjects); // logs objects as I expect them to be
    
        someArrayOfObjects.forEach(function(someObj) {
            console.log(someObj.name +" "+someObj.age +" "+ someObj.photo);
        })
    }
    somefunction(someArrayOfObjects);

/* outout */
/*
joe 32 joe.jpg
alice 5 alice.jpg
john 22 john.jpg
*/
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80941/discussion-on-answer-by-vinayakj-javascript-object-property-null-when-iteratin).